# PHP CURL Login with cookie

Tags: php, cookies, curl

I have a chat service that i would like to make an announcement bot that runs on cron to post daily updates to this chat. The url is `http://www6.cbox.ws/box/?boxid=524970&boxtag=7xpsk7&sec=form` I have tried various curl examples online but none seem to get the job done. My latest attempt which was a failure.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www6.cbox.ws/box/?boxid=&boxtag=&sec=profile&n=andysmith&k=0000000000000000000000000000000000000000");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://www6.cbox.ws/box/?boxid=&boxtag=&sec=profile&n=andysmith&logpword=iloveJD');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cbox.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cbox.txt');
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

I just need it to login and post a message.

Comment: Whats your question? What did your try, and why did it fail? What error message(s) did you see?

Comment: I tried to login and post a message but it just returns an empty page no errors

Comment: The code you posted requests that long URL providing some cookies from a file. What does the code suppose to do (post a comment)? What do you expect to receive from this request? There is no code that does authentication provided.

Answer (score 0):

try with

```
$result=curl_exec($ch);
//print $result;
if($result === false)
{
    echo '<br/>Curl error: '.curl_error($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    exit;           
}
```

and see the error

Note: if u r setting `'CURLOPT_REFERER'` , u need to set

```
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
```